# Is there a way to get dc out of a capacitor?

Tags: current-source, constant-current

The voltage and current during discharge of a capacitor is describe with an `e` function. I assume that thus a separate component is necessary (since `e` can't be transformed into something linear or constant).

Is there an element which can follow the decreasing voltage, store the difference to a predefined constant value and release the stored energy after the constant value has been undercut? Or something else?

I want to open a 12 V DC 1 A Solenoid valve for max. 10 seconds twice a day with the energy collected by a solar panel (12V or less if possible) over hours or days if possible. It would be nice to have a solution which can collect and store energy to open the valve over 2 to 7 days in order to make the system more reliable (yet, reliability is the least important factor). I assume that over that time there's enough energy collectable at every geo location in the world. The system is for watering plants and one cycle can be dropped or postponed if not enough energy is stored. The system is supposed to be operational for 10 years 24/7.

I have seen [capacitors with have V/DC in their voltage specification](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/450000-474999/451420-da-01-en-GREEN_CAP_3F_2_5V.pdf). Does that mean that they deliver DC which I could use to open [a 250 mA 12 V/DC valve](http://www.ebay.com/itm/12V-DC-small-plastic-Solenoid-Valve-for-Gas-Water-Air-N-C-normally-closed-/221926257892?hash=item33abd5f4e4:g:W6wAAOSwl9BWMeGS)?

Comment: Are you looking for a discharge resistor?

Comment: or maybe a diode?

Comment: The e-function is only there if you have a resistive load, if you have a constant current load, the current will of course be constant and the voltage will reduce linearly. I think what you are actually looking for is a buck-boost converter, which will step-down the voltage until it is under the predefined level and then step-up until energy runs out. In essence output a rather constant voltage "independent" of the input.

Comment: Back of the envelope: 10 s on time: 120 J needed energy, minimum required capacitor @12V: 1.7 F (every joule would be used, that is not going to happen, so it has to be larger). I'd recommend a battery.

Comment: @Arsenal A buck-boost converter is a DC-DC-converter. Can it deal with the linear decrease in voltage (!= DC) of a discharging capacitor?

Comment: @Arsenal I want to use the energy source repeatedly, i.e. an accu would be expensive give the fact that 5 supercaps à 2.5V with >= 1.7 F in parallel for 8 $ are more than sufficient.

Comment: Well if the voltage at the input would be constant there would be no need for a buck-boost converter (either buck or boost would do in a given application). The voltage shouldn't drop too fast otherwise it should be fine. Take LT-Spice and simulate what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you want something like a constant voltage power supply with the power input coming from a capacitor.  You perceive the problem as being that the capacitor voltage will drop as power is removed.

Yes this is possible.  A switching power supply can convert some voltage and current combination in to some other voltage and current combination out, with the output power being the input power minus some loss.  These types of supplies can be designed to have a fairly wide input voltage range, so can deal with the voltage from a capacitor that drops over time.

A good example that's not too hard to do is a switcher that can make regulated 5 V from let's say 6 to 24 V.  The current capability will be limited to what it can do with 6 V in, and the efficiency will suffer a bit due to the wide input voltage requirement, but this is something you can do yourself on your bench.  Get a large electrolytic 30 V capacitor or so, charge it up, and watch its voltage over time.

In this case the discharge curve at fixed output power will be a quadratic instead of exponential since you're removing constant power.  Since the input voltage range is 4:1, you get 15/16 of the stored energy out of the cap.

Consider the relatively low energy stored in caps, compared to batteries of the same size or mass.  Let's say you have a 10 mF cap that you start at 24 V.  That's only 2.9 J, of which you get 2.7.  Let's say the output of the supply is producing 5 V at 10 mA.  That's 50 mW.  Let's be pessimistic and say the supply is 60% efficient, so is draining the cap at 83 mW rate.  (2.7 J)/(83 mW) = 32 seconds, which is how long it will take for the cap to be drained to where the power supply can't maintain the output anymore.

Comment: We'd need a lot more information to make detailed recommendations. Like the rated values for the solar panel, geographical location (how much sun to expect), the duration of solenoid operation and duty rate, etc. But essentially yes, you can use a "small" solar panel to charge something (battery, capacitor, supercap, etc) and use that stored charge periodically. But the details will determine whether it will work or not, and for how long.

Comment: @rdtsc I explained more in the question.

Comment: A switching power supply may not be required. The solenoid's minimum hold current is probably much less than its operating current, so the supercaps could discharge to half the peak voltage or lower and the solenoid would stay operated.